# OpenMDAO v1.x: output of sub Group in ParallelGroup does not exist

Tags: parallel-processing, openmdao

When running in parallel I am unable to connect unknowns of subgroups in a `ParallelGroup()` even though I can connect to the subgroups' params. The code causing the problem (with names changed for clarity) is below. This code is within a group of a larger structure, but is the only place where MPI is being used:

```
for i in range(0, nTasks):
        self.connect('comp_a.output%i' % i, 'parallel_group.sub_group%i.param_a' % i)
        self.connect('input_param%i' % i, 'parallel_group.sub_group%i.param_b' % i)
        self.connect('parallel_group.sub_group%i.output' % i, 'comp_b.input%i' % i)
```

The first two connections seem to work fine, but the last one throws an error:

```
NameError: Source 'parallel_group.sub_group0.output' cannot be connected to target 'comb_b.input0': 'parallel_group.sub_group0.output' does not exist.
```

Also, if I comment out the offending line, then first line in the loop fails for the second process with the same error message:

```
NameError: Source 'comp_a.output1' cannot be connected to target 'parallel_group.sub_group1.param_a': 'parallel_group.sub_group1.param_a' does not exist.
```

All the connections work fine with our serial version of the code. The serial version is the same except that the sub_groups are added directly to the group this code is in rather than being wrapped in `parallel_group`.

I have tried to look over the tutorials and examples but have not been able to figure what might be wrong. I would really appreciate any suggestions of what to check or what may be wrong. Sorry to not post a complete code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a little unclear, but it sounds like you've added a new group in the parallel version of the code, named "parallel_group". When you did this, did you promote anything (or everything) from that group? If so, then you shouldn't add the parallel group into the variable name path for the connection.

That seems like the only thing likely to trip you up. I could try to debug a bit more if you can come up with a sample code you can post up here that would show the problem.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the address was the issue.